# Amazon ec2 - Deploying a python app

Tags: python, deployment, amazon-web-services, virtual-machine

I read though the whole docs and I learned a lot. Many parts really well documented. http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/

The problem is I am a newbie in web development. I know how to deploy my app on gae but I don't know how to deploy it on a remote virtual server.

Amazon doesn't really explain how to deploy a python app. The have complete solutions for .net java and php with 'ealsticbeanstalk', but not for python. They mentioned a 3rd party AMI called "ActivePython" but this didn't help me much.

I hope you can clear things up for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DJango try looking at bitnami
[bitnami's Django](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack#cloudImage) - this really makes things easier

I deployed a Django app on EC2 recently and my 'brain dump' is [here](http://nuclearcarrot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/brain-dump-of-getting-django-on-aws-ec2.html)

Comment: Well we want to use dynamoDB and a more lightweight framework such as webapp2. But thanks maybe I this will clear things up for me.

Comment: bitnami made my life easier so I'd give it a try - it'll also include various things which you'd have to install manually otherwise.

Comment: heroku makes life very easy - so it's probably a good place to start. Remember its just Amazon EC2 underneath it though.

Comment: yes i know. I hope it is possible to use dnyamoDB and s3 with heroku. I mean if I have more experience it shouldn't be too hard to transition back to ec2. Thanks

Comment: @johndpope Fixed. I moved my good posts to blogger after Posterous died.